# Playwright baseUrl in playwright.config.ts does not work in tests

Tags: base-url, playwright-test

I'm having an issue setting the baseURL for my project. By all tutorials that I watched and tried to replicate, setting the baseURL in the playwright.config.ts should do the trick. However, when I try to use inside the test or a class, the URL comes empty.

Basically what I did:

```
playwright.config.ts

import { PlaywrightTestConfig } from '@playwright/test';

const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  baseURL: 'https://example.com',
};

export default config;

mytest.spec.ts

test('Example test', async ({ page, config }) => {
 await page.goto('/');
}
```

Does the test need any type of import for it to work? Isn't playwright.config.ts global?

Comment: Sorry to revive this, but do you found the anwser? I also see the same behaviour basically having a baseURL is not behaving as the documentation declares, I'm force to do a reference to the config variable each time or write the entire URL

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before, in my case the Url was not properly set because I was using an env var that was not propagating correctly.

I was dong something like

```
use: {
  baseURL: process.env.URL <- I had a problem with my env variable
},
```

Just in case, I would suggest to hardcode the value directly in the `playwright.config.ts` only to debug and confirm that the value is there.

Also one of the best ways to finally fix any problem with the baseURL is to create a second node project, but this time using the [official playwright template](https://playwright.dev/docs/intro), you can install the playwright template with this command:

```
npm init playwright@latest
```

And then you can compare your wrong `playwright.config.ts` against the template.

---

Also remember that there are two places in the config file where you can set baseURL

```
import { defineConfig, devices } from '@playwright/test';

export default defineConfig({
  use: {
    baseURL: 'https://example.com', <-- Global for all test files
  },
  projects: [
  {
    name: 'chromium',
    use: {
      ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
      baseURL: 'https://anotherpage.com', <-- Overrides global baseURL
    }
  }
  ]
});
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

I believe that your `playwright.config.ts` should be:

```
import { defineConfig, devices } from '@playwright/test';

export default defineConfig({
  use: {
    baseURL: 'https://example.com',
  },
});
```

Now anywhere in the test if you use non-absolute URL, it will assume https://example.com as the base of the URL.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Unfortunally this was already tried and also it does not seem to work